# How to change Genymotion port

Tags: android, automated-tests, genymotion, appium, selendroid

I would like to run automatized test on different Genymotion devices in the same time. For this I have to give seperate port numbers for each device.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Genymotion Launcher, you are able to start multiple VMs.  Although these each will have the same default port (5555), they will get different IP addresses from the VirtualBox host-only adapter.  For example, I just launched two Genymotion machines and now `adb devices` shows:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
192.168.56.101:5555 device
192.168.56.102:5555 device
$
```

Each can be addressed separately by specifying IP address and port in your TCP/IP socket program, or by using `adb -s` if you're doing manual command line work or writing scripts.  I won't go into socket programming here, but here's a quick example of selective access using `adb` to see if the Location service is running on the second device:

```
$ adb -s 192.168.56.102:5555 shell service check location
Service location: found
$
```

Comment: Thanks that help some. I couldn't found any solution so far so I accept this answer because you answer my other question I haven't asked, yet :D