# How to reboot android device emulator in Genymotion

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

How can i test my application after reboot(BOOT COMPLETED) using Genymotion  I am using nexus 4 as device

```
<receiver android:name="com.template.SampleBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: do you want to reboot emulator?

Comment: yes for testing my notification after reboot

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the command line with `adb reboot`. It should restart your device.

To use adb you need to be inside the adb binary's folder. ie, `<android SDK>/platform-tools/` or `<genymotion folder>/tools/` if the android SDK is not installed. You can also these folders to your path to access it from anywhere.

Comment: This is the creator of Genymotion (context for those who don't know)

Comment: I'm far to be the Genymotion's creator but I'm part of the team that's right! :-)

Comment: @eyal-lezmy How? using genyshell, says command adb not found. is there another command line?

Comment: To use adb you need to be inside the adb binary's folder. ie, <android SDK>/platform-tools or <genymotion folder>/tools if the android SDK is not installed. Or you can add on the these folders to your path to access it from everywhere.

Comment: @eyal-lezmy Ironically this is NOT the correct answer and it's from one of the dev team. It ignores the actual question because you can't run `adb reboot` from the Genymotion Shell. Down voted until it's corrected.

Comment: @mike adb reboot had to be run from the command line (or terminal) and not from the Genyshell. Like evey adb command. I hope it will help you.

Comment: where is the genymotion folder?

Comment: Nothing happens on the latest Genymotion Emulator 23 API. After `adb reboot` from `C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools` Underscore `_` just blinks infinitely (https://s9.postimg.org/linusf90v/Screenshot_1.png)

Comment: @eyal-lezmy Could you take a look at some of my questions regarding Google play services on genymotion emulator. I repeatedly get the "Google play services has stopped". Over and over again. Tried every combination of devices and open gapps (about 30). Rebootibg, clearing data, storage, caches, nothing helps. And no useful info in catlog.

Comment: Please open a dedicated post to explain the problem

Comment: i agree with @mike, this is not the right answer since question is "in genymotion" and answer is out of geymotion context, it's a generic adb command.

Answer (score 17):

works for me on mac:

- open terminal
- go to /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platform-tools
- make sure adb is in directory (use ls command)
- ./adb reboot

Genymotion emulator restarts...

Comment: The platform-tools directory might be inside of the `android-sdk-macosx` directory depending on your Android Studio setup

Comment: No sdk folder within Android Studio

Comment: Path in mac - `~/Application/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/tools/adb`

Answer (score 11):

You can press emulator power button. When pressed, you will see option dialog. That dialog you can choose "Restart". Hope for help.

[image]

Comment: what you see the option?

Comment: power off ,Airplane mode,Silent Mode

Comment: I think you android version may be old. So you can use "Power Off". When Device Power On, reboot the Android OS.

Comment: genymotion version 2.2.2

Comment: No. I mean android os version of your device emulator. Eg: Android Version : 4.0

Comment: android version: 4.4.2

Comment: you can make 2 ways "Power Off" or "Close your emulator windows". that 2 ways are boot again your device. when boot again, If you test your application receiver don't run, you should check your code.

Comment: Genymotion 5.0 - only seeing Shut Down -.-

Comment: Remember to press the button in a "long hold". That's the point.

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution using also the answer from @eyal-lezmy and other stuff on the web.
If you have more than one device running, you can reboot a specific device in this way

1. LIST DEVICES

From `<genymotion-installer-path>` launch
    `genymotion-shell`

Inside the shell, run `devices`, take note of IP address and port of the device you want to reboot and exit.

2. REBOOT WITH ADB

From `<android-sdk-folder>/platform-tools` run

```
adb -s <device-ip>:<device-port> reboot
```

Comment: almost perfect... but where can i find out the device-port? "Genymotion Shell > devices list" does only show the ip address. thanks

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906377/how-to-change-genymotion-port I found that the port is 5555 for Genymotion devices

Answer (score 1):

When on linux I found the adb binary in `/path/to/genymotion/tools/adb`

In my case:

`~/genymotion/tools/adb reboot`

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Press and HOLD the power button on Genymotion's UI on the bottom right. That will pop up the menu to restart. The app will freeze up as it shuts down, but upon rebooting it you will see that it has restarted.

[image]

Comment: Sorry about how huge the picture is. New to posting ;)