# How to debug a broadcastreceiver that receive a RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED intent filter?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio

I need to debug an application that have a BroadcastReceiver that triggers when the device turns on. But Android Studio loses the connection when I turn off the smartphone. How to debug in this case? There's a way to do that?

Comment: For this kind of thing I just use log output to debug. Put something unique in all debug log entries, and grep for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate a system broadcast using ADB shell's [am command](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html#am) in your terminal.

```
$ adb shell
$ am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Your emulator/device will be rebooted while it still connected with Android Monitor. Note that you cannot simulate Local broadcast, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can test via

- Emulator, e.g. Genymotion, see
  [How to reboot android device emulator in Genymotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739957/how-to-reboot-android-device-emulator-in-genymotion)
- Rooted device, using a Hot/Soft reboot (triggered by e.g. `busybox killall system_server`). Most devices stay in contact with the adb server while hot booting.