# Android Studio doesn't see genymotion

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I updated  0.5 to 0.8.14 version of android studio ,  but now  studio doesn't see genymotion , what I must do now ? Thanks for all .

Edit :I solved the problem by updating genymotion too

Comment: I solved the problem by updating genymotion too

Comment: Christian Göllner's answer lower down should have been marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 172):

Genymotion by default uses its own ADB binary. If it has a different version than the one Android Studio is using, they can conflict and you get lots of issues. One of them can be Genymotion not being detected, and problems deploying apps.

I would recommend setting Genymotion to use the ADB/Android SDK that Android Studio is also using, instead of using the default one. That way you will avoid conflicts on future updates.

[image]

Comment: I have done it but it still conflicts.
I'm using ubuntu linux 14.04
The issue is that I have created link /usr/bin/adb to my customly installed adb
Then in genymotion I have provided my custom adb. 
But when I run genymotion emulator the console adb stops working. It tries to restart the server but can't

Comment: I specified path to sdk (same as the one used by Android Studio) on Linux, and the small checkmark did not appear, but it did work. I was seeing it in adb devices before, but android studio didn't. After doing this, Restarted Android Studio and now it's working. Thanks for sharing this

Comment: Thanks Christian. Your solution worked for me. I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 and I hadn't specified correct Android SDK path. It was set to default path.

Comment: Thank you. This answer should have been chosen as the right answer but author didn't chose anything...

Comment: Man I just love SO. Definitely not everything with it, but some

Answer (score 26):

You MUST install the plug-in for Genymotion first, click the "File" tab locate the "Plug-in" option, down the bottom, search for Genymotion, then install. After the installation, you need to restart Android Studio, after that, you will see the Genymotion icon near the "Sdk Manager" icon, click on it, then just specify the location of your Genymotion installation. Also, make sure you have "Oracle Virtual Box" installed in order to use Genymotion, it is a requirement.

**Edit-**
[image]

Then your genymotion virtual machines come up, click the one you want (I think it has to be off for start to be clickable/not greyed) then click start,

[image]

then click that green Play icon near the centre of the button bar below the menu bar, then the genymotion virtual machine should appear listed under 'running devices'. highlight it and click ok, and it should launch and show your program.

[image]

Comment: On the genymotion device manager screen, the instance shows Status = On, yet in the Choose Device screen that follows, I get a blank screen!  There appears to be an issue with geny and the latest android studio 2

Comment: Installing this plugin is ABSOLUTELY unnecessary.

Comment: @VSG24 why not?

Comment: @Biu Because all it does is add a button to Android Studio that lets user open a window with VMs listed in it (The very same thing can be done using Genymotion program itself)

Comment: @VSG24 I don't know, that was what I did to make Android Studio see Genymotion

Answer (score 9):

Open Genymotion Shell,use command line `devices list` will show the [image]   then in cmd use command line `adb connect IP address`.if not show devices in studio.maybe restart studio.

Answer (score 6):

One words(you need find your devices ip):
`adb connect 192.168.***.***:5555`

---

2019-03-19 09:10:00

My enviroment：

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Genymotion Version 3.0.1
- Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
- AndroidStudio version 3.3.2

My problem:

1. adb devices : `list is empty`
2. no usb devices or running emulators detected

My solution :

1. `cd /opt/genymobile/genymotion`
2. `./genymotion-shell`
3. `devices list` (if no running devices start one)
4. in other terminal run commond : `adb connect yourDeviceIP:5555`

Reference:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27262302/7707781
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24926960/7707781

Comment: The genymotion-shell tip was very important! Helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I close genymotion, then clicked on Run button , so the "Select Deploymnt Target" dialog opened.  after that I open genymotion as administrator, start virtual device and after a minute it appear in "Select Deploymnt Target" dialog.

I think the key point is that genymotion has to be run after android studio, and maybe with "Select Deploymnt Target" dialog has to be opened!

It works for me anyway

Answer (score 3):

After few research I found a solution, open task bar and just End Process the adb.exe, hit run (android studio) and adb will be recreated and your genymotion emulator will be on the list. Thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

When I updated Android Studio to 3.4, same problem is occured in my system.

1. Open Genymotion program,
2. Click "Genymotion" text on the upper left corner,
3. "Settings" --> "ADB" --> check "Use Genymotion Android Tools (default)"
4. Restart Genymotion program.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Go to Genymotion → Setting → ADB → Use Custom Android SDK tools 
  (`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`).
- Go to Android Studio → Search for "Genymotion Device Manager" → Specific the part for Genymotion (`C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion`).
- Go to Android Studio → View → Appearent → Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

first install genymotion plugin and restart and android studio.After the restart you will see genymotion device manager icon near sdk manager icon select it and add the path where u have genymotion folder.If u didn't see the icon then search for genymotion device manager u will get it

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem once. I must connect it to adb server manually and it worked fine!
just follow these steps:

1- open your emulator

2- after running, open oracle vm virualBox manager app

3- double click on your running emulator. you will see Ip management value. that's the emulator local ip address

4- go to your sdk manager path, then platform-tools directory

5- open cmd on this directory (or use cd command)

6- run adb connet ipAddress:5555

after that you will see connected to ip address text on the screen. go back to android studio and you see adb has appeared!