# Genymotion Emulator Error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion

Genymotion Emulator Error

I'm repeatedly getting this error

[image: Genymotion Error]

After reading this thread [Android Studio doesn't see genymotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261474/android-studio-doesnt-see-genymotion)

I have successfully included my ADB Location in Genymotion

[image: ADB Location]

But it is still showing me Android Studio "Status Off" message
[image: Status Off]

This was the default configuration of the Emulator
[image: Genymotion Emulator Setting]

And this was the Oracle Virtual Box Setting [!OVB_Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56BqV.jpg)

And after reducing the system processor from 4 to 2 and removing all the Emulators in my Android Studio. It's still giving me the error mentioned in the top. And this is Virtual Box Error:

[image: Virtual Box Error]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: i had same issue. my mistake was i did not checked all checkbox while installation. reinstall "genymotion and virtualBox" with checking all checkbox did trick for me. hope this also work for you.

Comment: Thanks @Rumit I did tried it. Didn't helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible issues here.

If you use Windows Creator Update and your version of VirtualBox is the one bundled with Genymotion (5.0.28), then you need to update to VirtualBox 5.1.26 (see https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#compatible-virtualbox-versions)

If this does not help, you might have a firewall which prevents the communication between Genymotion and VirtualBox. In this case, looking at the VBoxHardening.log file mentioned in the last screenshot can help figuring it out. You can find more information about this file in this [post from VirtualBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=82106).

Comment: Thanks @AurelienGateau It is giving me 5.2.6 as a new update for VirtualBox. If it works I will update it here. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes. This 5.2.6 update worked. Thank you so much @AurelienGateau You saved my day! :)