# Genymotion device is unknown in Android Studio device selector

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

I started one Genymotion device, but it always be unknown in the Android Studio device list.
And when I run app, it failed:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to open sync connection!
Error while Installing APK
```

Genymotion version is 2.12.0 (I have already re-installed it), Android Studio version is 3.0.1 (it works for real device)

It's really weird, please help, thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261474/android-studio-doesnt-see-genymotion

Comment: @MiteshVanaliya yes, I have tried this, but its different, coz I can see the Genymotion device, the problem is that the device is unknown.