# Don't see genymotion virtual device at list

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

Yesterday my emulator worked stable and good. But today I can't launch my app because I don't see any of my genymotion devices. I have reinstalled my AS and Genymotion. I have reinstalled my virtual devices. But I still don't see any of my devices. I thought that I have problems with AS and I create AVD at Android Studio, and I managed to create a new device, but I didn't manage to launch my app. I don't know how to solve this problem. I [saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261474/android-studio-doesnt-see-genymotion) this question. As I see at genymotion dashboard that my virtual device continue booting and can't finish his booting anyway.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found solution!
Looks, like this is some adb or Genymotion bug.
To solve this, you must manually connect adb to running Genymotion Device
In first, you need to know Androids internal IP. You can find it in window title of Genymotion device.
Next:

1. cd to your Android SDK dir
2. cd to platform-tools
3. ./adb connect 192.168.57.102:5555

where 192.168.57.102 is my IP address of Genymotion Virtual Device. You must put here your own

Comment: I think it's a new bug of genymotion and suddenly occurs in recent days.

Comment: nice. you are the man. was trying to connect via the private ip and wasn't connecting. thanks for the help!

Comment: @rock3r I tried what you recommended and received the following error message "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it (10061)."  Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: @r0ck3r, Genymotion came out with a new update (Version 3.0.2) and they seem to have resolved the issue with booting issue. Now we can boot up emulators without using: adb connect.

Comment: If you don't understand what cd commands are. You can use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27262104/8650422 that may solve the conflict. It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

*Update: This is no longer necessary with Genymotion 3.0.2*

This is likely caused by a behavior change introduced in ADB in the Android SDK, in platform-tools 28.0.2.

The easiest workaround for now is to downgrade platform-tools to 28.0.1. Unfortunately the SDK manager does not let you do that easily, so you have to manually download the zip for your platform.

The urls for platform-tools 28.0.1 are:

- Linux: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.1-linux.zip
- macOS: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.1-darwin.zip
- Windows: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.1-windows.zip

You have to:

1. Download the right zip
2. Kill any running `adb` process
3. Find the `platform-tools` folder in your Android SDK installation, and backup/rename it
4. Unpack the zip in the parent of the `platform-tools` folder

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

Go to Android-SDK\platform-tools
./adb kill-server

Comment: You may also have to do the ./adb connect step as well that was mention in the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The easiest way to fix this error is by downloading SDK Platform Tools as a zip file from https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html, unzip it and replace the current platform-tools folder in the SDK folder.