# Genymotion Virtual Device Appears to be Running but Appears to be Stuck on Booting

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion, boot

I'm currently having a problem with my Genymotion Virtual Device where I'm able to boot up an emulator, (when it opens up,) and it responds to swipes or opens up app, but the status of the device shows that the device is stuck on booting.
Screenshot:
[image]

When I check with "adb devices" it doesn't show up as an active device. I've attempted to reinstall Genymotion and VirtualBox, as well as create a new virtual devices, but it doesn't appear to get rid of the issue. I'm not sure what to look for or what to adjust to get Genymotion working again. Vitrual Box and Android SDK directory appear correct.

Comment: Here I have posted temporary solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157822/dont-see-genymotion-virtual-device-at-list

Comment: @r0ck3r, I see what you mean by temporary. Thanks for the link. It works after I connect to the IP address, but if you close the emulators and launch them at a later time, you get the same problem. Wonder if this is what got messed up with Genymotion's latest update. Has this already been reported to Genymotion?

Comment: Genymotion has a new update (Version 3.0.2) which resolves the issue with emulators stuck on booting status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I face this problem several time and i didn't find any solution until now.

I update Genymotion to version **3.0.2** and now work fine.

As in release note says

> We have fixed an incompatibility with the adb tool bundled in the platform-tools 28.0.2 package of the Android SDK, which caused failures to start virtual devices.
>
> This new version of adb changed the behavior of the “adb connect
>   :” command by making the “port” part mandatory. This
>   broke Genymotion Desktop in a few places where it did not pass the
>   port. We have adjusted the way we call “adb connect” and also updated
>   the version we ship with the product to match the one in
>   platform-tools 28.0.2.

Source  [www.genymotion.com](https://www.genymotion.com/product-release-note/desktop/)