# None of the Genymotion Emulator are showing up under connected devices in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion, amd-processor

I have successfully installed Android Studio, it works really great thus far.

I have also downloaded Genymotion which came with virtual box, that works really great thus far as well.

In Genymotion , I added the file path from Android Studio Tools which I copied and paste from SDK Manager.

In Android Studio, as well, I added the path (I believe the Default file path it is): `C:\Program File\GenyMobile\Genymotion`

I then started the device in Genymotion of my choice, the emulator showed up (This worked out great!)

Then I went to Android Studio (while the device in Genymotion status states booting) to run the program. The emulator from Genymotion didn't come up under connected devices (`<none>`).

There is also a little pop up in the same window that says:

> No USB Devices or running emulators detected

The question here is:

Why is it that the emulator from Genymotion isn't showing under connected Devices)? Is it that I did not install a specific Android Tool?

I am using an AMD machine - Windows 10 hence I downloaded and chose to work with Genymotion instead as the emulator in Android Studio, is taking very long to come and nothing really comes up on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, ADB does not connect with the Genymotion virtual device. That is a bug of Genymotion actually. So you have to manually do that. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55180833/8470239) to do it manually.
And also you will have to install the plugin for Android Studio as well. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55488632/8470239) to install the plugin.

You can find the IP of the virtual device in the device's window.

Comment: I have installed the Genymotion plugin in Android Studio prior to my previous post.

Comment: Thank you, I only had to manually connect genymotion device to adb manually. It has finally worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem and now, I fixed it.

1. **Make sure Genymotion to be installed**.
   If not, please download genymotion file to install, such as: genymotion-3.0.2-linux_x64.bin. Following:

   > https://linuxhint.com/install_genymotion_android_emuator_ubuntu/
2. **Choose Custom android sdk tools in genymotion**

   > $ cd ~/genymotion

> $ ./genymotion

now, genymotion window will be shown 
[Genymotion window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTdQB.png)

Then click **Genymotion > Settings > ADB** , choose **Use custom android sdk tools** and click to **Browse** to android sdk folder. After this, you will see *"This folder is valid"*[Genymotion ADB Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm3sh.png)

3. **Install genymotion in android studio and browse to genymotion folder**
   Open android studio, click **File > Settings > Plugins** , search "genymotion" and click install to download and install genymotion. [genymotion plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhYPl.png) 
   click **Apply** and **OK** .

After that, open again **File > Settings** . you will see Genymotion in botton of window. choose **Genymotion** and browse to *Genymotion folder* [Genymotion folder[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWEjg.png)
, click **Apply** and **OK**
Restart android studio, click **View** and choose **Toolbar**, you will see genymotion icon in toolbar.
Now, you can create, open genymotion device and run project.

Comment: If you got error : **unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'** , please following the link to fix : [https://upokary.com/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle/]