# Android studio cannot find the virtual device of genymotion

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a virtual device by genymotion, but android studio is unable to find the device.

I have started the device by virtual box. I also tried killing the adb server. But none of the things worked.

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142055/genymotion-device-doesnt-appear-on-device-chooser-android-studio

Comment: I have tried it

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565495/none-of-the-genymotion-emulator-are-showing-up-under-connected-devices-in-androi

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to the fact that you haven't installed genymotion plugin properly. So you need to install this plugin in Plugin section of Android Studio. 
1) Start a device from geynymotion. 
2) Click on Run-> Edit Configuration in Android Studio. 
Genymotion's device will be available now.

Comment: I can't find "Deployment target option" in edit configuration

Comment: It should be available by adding the plugin. You got to find another way if it doesn't work. And, you won't find the deployment target option in edit configuration..!