# Genymotion virtual device stuck on booting

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, genymotion, boot

The virtual device seems to be running but its status is stuck on booting so I can't install `GApps` (which I need to test some app) also it doesn't appear in the list of devices in `Android studio`.

[image: screenshot of Genymotion virtual device]

I found this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157822/dont-see-genymotion-virtual-device-at-list) to manually connect `adb` to `Genymotion`, but I still have an issue with `GApps` how can I install them?

Comment: What Genymotion version are you running?

Comment: @yasin the most recent one 3.0.1 under Linux

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same issue previously. However, what I did was that I closed Genymotion, reopen it and restarted the device.Then went to Android Studio and run the app. You should then see the device under 'Connected Devices'. You should be able to see your design on the emulated device.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem, what worked for me was running:

```
adb devices
```

If that doesn't work, try running

```
adb kill-server  
adb start-server
```